# Visa requirements for travel from Rwanda to Lesotho

Tags: transit-visas, lesotho, rwandan-citizen

Who would want to help me on this?
I am Rwandan and need to travel to Lesotho for a two weeks consultancy with UNESCO. Do I have to apply for a South African transit visa since it's the only route to arrive there?

Answer (score 2):

You won't need a visa to transit South Africa if you remain in the international transit area of the airport.

Timatic, the database which airlines use to verify passenger travel documents, states:

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>   Visa required, except for Passengers transiting through Cape
>   Town (CPT), Durban (DUR), Johannesburg (JNB) or Lanseria (HLA)
>   with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third
>   country. They must stay in the international transit area of
>   the airport and have documents required for the next
>   destination.

You will need a visa to enter Lesotho. If you haven't already gotten the visa, you can obtain an e-visa online at [Lesotho's official e-visa web site](http://evisalesotho.com/).

Comment: On the other hand, it seems as though for many travelers the more reasonable route would be to fly to Johannesburg and drive from there.  This would be rather less costly and would take around the same amount of time, at least for the dates I checked.  In that case, it would be necessary to have a visa for South Africa, of course, but I found some articles online suggesting that South Africa has not granted visas to Rwandans [since 2014](https://www.theeastafrican.co.ke/news/ea/South-Africa-visa-hurdle-hurting-Rwanda/4552908-4606088-g4dfd5z/index.html).